# JPA OneToMany with JoinTable delete foreign key failure

Tags: jpa

My `Patientbooking class` uses a jointable. The following is the code. `Appointment` has no `Patientbooking`.

```
public class Patientbooking implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable
    (
      name="patientbooking_appointments",
      joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="patientbooking_id", referencedColumnName="id") },
      inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="appointments_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true) }
  )
    private List<Appointment> appointments;

    ...
}
```

When I delete `Appointment` I get this error.

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`soebala/patientbooking_appointments`, CONSTRAINT `patientbooking_appointments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`appointments_id`) REFERENCES `appointments` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are doing a constraint violation. Put in your code

```
cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
```